# Monitor which folder has used the disk storage

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, storage

I got a mac air with only 256 GB storage.  Some apps must be using the storage and after deleting and moving everything I can (down to relocate mail and dropbox to external disk using symbolic links and their own folder), the storage is still kept on dropping. It lost quite quickly down to 0.01G per 15 minutes. Looking using du df or visual is hard to spot so far.

Is there any way (shell script etc.) to monitor which folder is increasing in size over time? (Space approach)

If that is not possible, how about a script to monitor any directories that have been modified in the last 15 minutes? (Time approach)

Many advice I found is only on one folder or one layer e.g. home/* but not the whole directory structure.  Possibly to have a way to spot out an offending directory?

Comment: There are many processes that can gobble up available disk space.  Mobile Backups (~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync) is a common culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like omni disk sweeper to see where my space is going. Link: https://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnidisksweeper/

To see which folders have changed in the last 15 minutes, run this from a command-line: `$ find / -type d -cmin -15`

Comment: Thanks all.  / -type d -cmin -15 helped to find that it is the time machine local backup issues - sudo tmutil disablelocal  and rm -f /.MobileBackup/ plus delete some backup.  The MobileBackup is the one I usually go to but not this time.

Comment: But it is the omnidisksweeper find the real answer - the dropbox even after you use an external disk it still use internal hard drive i.e. .dropbox/instance4/...

Comment: @DennisNg great! Please mark my answer ad correct by clicking the checkmate near the up/down arrows.

Answer (score 0):

There are many utilities to track disk usage.  My favorite: https://daisydiskapp.com/